# Deallocating memory through a function - is this right?

Tags: c++

I was just a little confused why the same  memory address was being printed when I attempted to delete a newly allocated variable through a function, I am guessing that no memory was leaked or pointer dangled.

The same memory address was printed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void deallocater(int *p)
{
    delete p;
    p = nullptr; // memory deleted and no dangling pointer right?
}

int main()
{
    int *x = new int(1);
    cout<<x;
    deallocater(x);

    cout<<endl<<x; // why is the same memory address being printed?

    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming that the function worked successfully

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling the function

```
void deallocater(int* p)
{
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
}
```

via

```
deallocater(x);
```

copies the value of `x` to `p`. Thus within `deallocater()` the local variable `p` is assigned `nullptr`. However, the variable `x` of the calling program is not altered.

You may achieve what you appear to want by taking the argument by reference:

```
void deallocater(int* &p)
{
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
}
```

However, memory allocation and de-allocation should not be split apart into different and unrelated functions to avoid the danger of dangling pointers and/or memory leaks. Instead, good C++ code contains hardly any `delete` statements and few `new` statements (to initialize smart pointers), but instead use standard library constructs (containers and smart pointers) for memory management.

Comment: Even though your answer accomplishes the same result as Kingsley's solution, I prefer this one because it doesn't require changing the body of the function.

Comment: "However, the variable x of the calling program is not altered" ...many thanks for the insightful feedback

Answer (score 2):

The code cannot change the content of the pointer `p` in `deallocater()`, thus it still shows the same value when printed.  After the call `p` still has the same (pointer) value, but the memory it points to is freed.  This is known as a "dangling reference".

To update the pointer, use a double-pointer, or a reference to a pointer:

```
void deallocater(int **p)
{
    delete *p;
    *p = nullptr; // memory deleted and no dangling pointer right?
}

int main()
{
    int *x = new int(1);
    cout<<x;
    deallocater( &x );

    cout<<endl<<x; // why is the same memory address being printed?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a reference for parameters that aren't optional.

Comment: Very informative, never knew the pointer was still dangling! at least the memory was freed lol, many thanks

Comment: @Swordfish - I disagree, can you cite references better than Google's C++ coding standard (https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)?  Or is this a personal style choice?

Comment: The language has a built-in mechanism to pass by reference -- it's clearly preferable to use that directly instead of simulating it by passing by pointer

Comment: @Kingsley Are you referring to [Output_Parameters](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Output_Parameters)? They don't explain the \*why\* there. And this "Style Guide" is just one of many.